# Easiest way to turn NSMutableDictionary into an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary that is finished loading it's data. The dictionary has data like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

The data is just NSStrings. So like this would be an example:

```
dict[@"a"] = @"a";
dict[@"b"] = @"b";
dict[@"c"] = @"c";
```

I don't know what the data will be till the loop that generates it is run (but it will be like the pattern above).

What's the best/easiest way to turn this into an NSArray?

Comment: What should the final array look like?  Do you want the values, the keys, both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert it into an `NSArray` only keeping its keys, you should use

```
NSArray *keysArray =  [dict allKeys];
```

If you want values, you can use

```
NSArray *valuesArray = [dict allValues];
```

If you want both, you can add them.